# How to change database for all cards in a neodash dashboard

Tags: neo4j, neodash

For a given neo4j server at work, we have multiple database using the same schema. I would like to be able to quickly change the queried database of my neo4j neodash dashboard, but right now the only way of changing DB that I see is via the edit menu of each card, meaning I need to edit each one every time I want to change DB.

Is there a way in the interface to quickly change between DB for a given neodash?